# Method which use for loop inserts duplicates to StringBuilder

Tags: java

I've a method ( this is only example which I did to show my problem ) but it's very similar to this. The method has a for loop where are performed some actions like below. The problem is that the return message looks like `Your number 13 is not the highest one., 25, 11, 2, 2, 28, 28, 23, 22, 17` instead of `Your number 13, 25, 11, 2, 2, 28, 23, 22, 17 is not the highest one.` I've few if statements like those in the example which append a string several times. How could I get rid of the duplicates instead of the message as above or sometimes the message is added several times `Your number 13 is not the highest one., 25, 11, 2, 2, 28, 28, 23, 22, 17` `Your number 13 is not the highest one., 25, 11, 2, 2, 28, 28, 23, 22, 17` and so on. Should I use a map or what? Sometimes the message does not have key in this case the number, but it's just a string which instead of added once is added twice etc.

This is only a quick example of my problem this method below is extended and there are more appends like this one.

```
 public static String process() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Random rm = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int number = rm.nextInt(30);
            if (sb.length() != 0) {
                sb.append(", " + number);
            } else {
                sb.append("Your number " + number + " is not the highest one.");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Debug it and you'll see in a sec

Answer (score 0):

You only need to append the numbers inside your loop. Move the rest of the message outside of it:

```
public static String process() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random rm = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int number = rm.nextInt(30);
        if (sb.length() != 0) {
            sb.append(", " + number);
        } else {
            sb.append(number);
        }
    }
    return "Your number " + sb.toString() + " is not the highest one.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String process()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random rm = new Random();
    sb.append("Your number ").append(rm.nextInt(30)); // code is here to skip coma before the first number
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) // NOTE: i starts from 1, because the first number has been added in the code above
    {
         sb.append(", ").append(rm.nextInt(30));
    }
    sb.append(" is not the highest one.");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

And a bit modified version of @MushifAliNawaz:

```
  public static String process()
  {
      String numbers = ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0, 30).limit(10)
                .mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
      return String.format("Your number %s is not the highest one.", numbers);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `List<Integer>` here and instead of manually checking and appending the commas, let Java automatically do that for you:

```
public static String process() {
    Random rm = new Random();
    List<Integer> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        randomNumbers.add(rm.nextInt(30));
    }
    return String.format("Your number %s is not the highest one.", randomNumbers.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
}
```

I have used `Collectors.joining` with Stream API here.

**Output (3 runs):**

```
Your number 17, 1, 19, 5, 4, 11, 7, 4, 12, 5 is not the highest one.
Your number 29, 17, 4, 23, 28, 28, 16, 2, 23, 7 is not the highest one.
Your number 0, 1, 18, 18, 25, 24, 13, 3, 13, 14 is not the highest one.
```

Comment: Why wouldn't omit the loop and just use streams like that: `String.format("Your number %s is not the highest one.",
            ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(0, 30).limit(10)
                    .mapToObj(String::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
        );` ?

Comment: @Michel_T. Yeah, that would be more simple.